# Get URL from within remote EJB bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have created a remote EJB bean, deployed it into ejb-container and I'm able to call it's method remotely. Now I want to get the url on which the remote EJB bean is located from within remote EJB bean.

Here some code. Remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface ExampleService {

void example();

}
```

EJB:

```
@Stateful
public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService {

   @Override
   public void example() {
       //get Remote Url When This Method Is Called
   }

}
```

For example : if remote bean is located on remote.bean.com:8081, then 
inside ExampleServiceImpl.example() I want to get this url (remote.bean.com:8081) without passing it directly as input param.

I've been trying to get some information from SessionContext:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
SessionContext sctxLookup = (SessionContext)ic.lookup("java:comp/EJBContext");
```

, but got nothing useful there.
Is it even possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Example of calling remote EJB deployed on weblogic

```
private static Calculator getRemoteCalculator() {
    Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");    


    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        return (Calculator) ctx.lookup("myCalculator#com.javaee.Calculator");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Where Calculator is

```
@Remote
public interface Calculator {

    public int add(int a, int b);

}
```

And implementation is

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "myCalculator")
public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {
    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you even read my question? I don't have any problems calling ejb remotely (I've wrote this in the first sentence of my question)